App Store Testing Failed: App Opens Settings
My App Store submission keeps getting rejected because my flutter app "keeps opening the settings app" upon launching it during testing. I can't seem to reproduce the issue and i have tested on a real iPhone, simulated iPhone, real iPad, simulated iPad, and Android device.
I have no idea what i should be looking for or the reason why the app launches the settings app.
Here is a my info.plist file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>************</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>************</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow media library access to send pictures</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow camera access to send pictures</string>
    <key>NSFileProviderDomainUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow mic access to send audios</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow photo library access to send pictures</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow photo library access to send pictures</string>
    <key>NSUserNotificationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need permission to send you notifications and alerts.</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>kTCCServiceMediaLibrary</key>
    <string>Allow audio access to send audios</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>

Please help with pointers of what i should be looking out for. I can also provide additional snippets if it may be helpful for debugging.


if um not wrong, Permission-Handler package hass appSetting() function to go to appSetting, u r using it wrong. check 1) r u asking for permission or not for camera,microphone,location etc or directly send them to appSettings 2) if user didn't give any then u r sending them to app-settings or not. if that's ur case then u should make a snackbar to goto setting if user denies basic permission

The most likely causes for the Settings app opening on launch are:
Permissions being requested too early (especially camera, location, Bluetooth, etc.).
Background modes being enabled that trigger certain settings requests.
Using Firebase or similar services that might inadvertently ask for permissions on launch.
Review these areas and try to isolate what’s triggering the Settings screen to prevent the issue from happening during Apple’s review process.

The app is fairly simple. The only permission requested is notification. I also thought it might be firebase as you have suggested and so i reviewed the code but i was unable to see anything outside the ordinary. I'll keep checking and post a feedback.
